# JPA using @SQLInsert throws Parameter index out of range

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, parameters, spring-data-jpa

```
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseModel implements Serializable {
 private static final Long serialVersionUID = -1442801573244745790L;

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Long id;

 @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
 @Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class)
 private LocalDateTime createAt = LocalDateTime.now();

 @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
 @Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class)
 private LocalDateTime updateAt = LocalDateTime.now();
}


@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_vip_code")
@SQLInsert(sql = "insert ignore into tb_vip_code (code, duration) values (?, ?)")
public class VipCode extends BaseModel {
private static final Long serialVersionUID = -4697221755301869573L;

private String code;
private Integer duration;
private Integer status = 0;
private Long userId;

public VipCode() {}
}

@Test
public void addOne() throws Exception {
    VipCode vipCode = new VipCode();
    vipCode.setCode("123456");
    vipCode.setDuration(1);
    service.addOne(vipCode);
}

create table tb_vip_code
(
id bigint auto_increment
    primary key,
code varchar(20) not null,
status int default '0' not null,
user_id bigint null,
duration int not null,
create_at datetime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null,
update_at timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null,
constraint tb_vip_code_code_uindex unique (code)
);
```

All code as above, I am trying to use a custom sql to save object, but it throws an exception:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (3 > number of parameters, which is 2).

I only have two parameters; why does it say it needed three?

Answer (score 0):

The SQL statement specified by `@SQLInsert` gets the fields of your entity bound as parameters.

You have at least 4 attributes in your `VipCode` entity directly, and I suspect even more from the `BaseModel` class it inherits from. But your SQL statment expects only two parameters.

To fix the problem remove the superfluous attributes from the entity, add parameters for them to the query or mark them as `@Transient`.